# how to get number of elements of a specific priority in POSIX message queue

Tags: c, operating-system, posix, ipc, message-queue

I can get the total number of messages in queue with `msgctl(int msqid, int cmd, struct msqid_ds *buf)` with using `IPC_STAT` as cmd and the `msg_qnum` field of `msqid_ds` struct. Is there a way to know the number of elements for a specific priority like 1, 2 etc.?